# можно ли двигать объект без перерисовки?

Tags: python, turtle

пишу программу на python, используя библиотеку turtle и хотел спросить можно ли как то поместить в переменную уже готовый объект? типо такого:

```
t = turtle.circle(50)
```

и потом что бы я мог по окну двигать уже целый круг а не просто эту стрелочку которая рисует. Есть ли такая возможность?  Что бы можно было как то так написать:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
a = t.circle(50)
a.goto(1000,500)
```

и двигался целый круг?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С кругом сложно, это библиотека для детишек - с чемто более крутым надо переходить на pygame.

Но тут есть turtle.Shape, в который можно положить картинку или полигон.

```
s = turtle.Shape("compound")
poly1 = ((-20,-20), (-20, 20), (20,20))
s.addcomponent(poly1, "red", "blue") 
poly2 = ((-10,-10),(-10, 10),(10,10),(10,-10))
s.addcomponent(poly2, "blue", "red") 
turtle.register_shape("myshape", s) # добавляем фигуру на поле
turtle.shape("myshape") # выбираем её для управления

turtle.goto(200,200)
```